# Change state on click then change again after delay and show message in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a button with the text "Add to Cart". On click, the text should change to "Loading..." for a few seconds. After that, the text should change again to "View Cart" and a message should be displayed.

I know I need to change state on the same element twice and also use some kind of flag to know when the button text changes to "View Cart" to display the hidden message, but unsure of the best approach.

```
import React from 'react';

class ProductAddToCart extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: "Add to Cart"};
 }

 handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ text: "Loading..." });
    //AFTER 2 SECONDS, CHANGE LOADING TEXT TO "VIEW CART" AND SHOW PARAGRAPH BELOW WITH "ITEM ADDED TO CART" MESSAGE NEXT TO BUTTON
 };

 render() {
    return (
        <div id="product-add-to-cart">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-left" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.text}</button>
            <p className="hidden">Item added to cart!</p>
        </div>
    );
 }
}

export default ProductAddToCart;
```

Comment: are you actually going to be doing some processing on click after you set the value to Loading? 

I would usually add a property of `isLoading` to my state, then in my functions I would set the state value of `isLoading` to true, then at the end of my function set it again to but to false

Then you can simply use a ternary operator to toggle the text

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by using a setTimeout, like so:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ text: "Loading..." });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ text: "view cart", showParagraph: true });
    }, 2000);
};
```

And on the p:

```
<p className={this.state.showParagraph ? '' : 'hidden'}>...</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answers put it with a setTimeout you can handle this. But i'll do it in the callback of the setState just to make sure that the state has changed properly:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ text: "Loading..." }, () => {  
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ text: "view cart", showParagraph: true });
      }, 2000);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the program wait 2 seconds before changing the text you can use the `setTimeout` function.

```
handleClick = () => {
    // your code
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({text: 'View Cart', showSuccessMessage: true});
    }, 2000);
};
```

You may also want to consider changing how you hide and show elements in your `render()` method. One such way of doing it is by only showing it if a state variable is set (`showSuccessMessage` above). I would do something like this:

```
render = () => {
    const {showSuccessMessage, text} = this.state;
    return (
        <div id="product-add-to-cart">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-left" onClick={this.handleClick}>{text}</button>
            {showSuccessMessage ? <p>Item added to cart!</p> : null} // using the inline if/else format
        </div>
    );
};
```